# How does numpy.concatenate work on lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, concatenation

I'm trying to figure out, why the following code does not work:

```
import numpy as np

failList = [[[1], [2]],
           [[3, 4, 5, 6], [7]],
           [[8], [9]],
           [[10], [11, 12]],
           [[13], [14, 15, 16]]]

goodList = [[[1], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7], [8]],
           [[9], [10], [11, 12], [13], [14, 15, 16]]]

goodList2 = [[[1], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7], [8]],
            [[9], [10], [11, 12], [13], [14, 15, 16]],
            [[9], [10], [11, 12], [13], [14, 15, 16]]]

myLists = [failList, goodList, goodList]

for l in myLists:
    print([len(l[i]) for i in range(len(l))])
    print([len(l[i][j]) for i in range(len(l)) for j in range(len(l[i]))])
    try:
        np.concatenate(l)
        print("worked")
    except:
        print("failed")
```

The output is:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
failed
[5, 5]
[1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
worked
[5, 5, 5]
[1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]
worked
```

Can someone explain, why the first list can't be concatenated but the others can?

Comment: It turns each element into an array. The fail case is a mix of 2d numeric and 1d object dtype

Answer (score 2):

`concatenate` makes an array from each list element, and then joins those on the desired axis.  If the shapes don't match, it raises an error:

```
In [80]: failList = [[[1], [2]],
    ...:            [[3, 4, 5, 6], [7]],
    ...:            [[8], [9]],
    ...:            [[10], [11, 12]],
    ...:            [[13], [14, 15, 16]]]
    ...:            
In [81]: [np.array(a) for a in failList]
Out[81]: 
[array([[1],
        [2]]),
 array([list([3, 4, 5, 6]), list([7])], dtype=object),
 array([[8],
        [9]]),
 array([list([10]), list([11, 12])], dtype=object),
 array([list([13]), list([14, 15, 16])], dtype=object)]
In [82]: [np.array(a).shape for a in failList]
Out[82]: [(2, 1), (2,), (2, 1), (2,), (2,)]
In [83]: np.concatenate([np.array(a) for a in failList])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-c3434632bd7e> in <module>()
----> 1 np.concatenate([np.array(a) for a in failList])

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

The elements of `failedList` for different kinds of arrays, some are 2d numeric, and some are 1d object.  `concatenate` can't join those.

`column_stack` does work:

```
In [87]: np.column_stack(failList)
Out[87]: 
array([[1, list([3, 4, 5, 6]), 8, list([10]), list([13])],
       [2, list([7]), 9, list([11, 12]), list([14, 15, 16])]],
      dtype=object)
In [88]: _.shape
Out[88]: (2, 5)
```

That's because it reshapes the (2,) shaped arrays to (2,1).  Now it has a list of 5 (2,1) arrays which it can join on the 2nd dimension, producing a (2,5) array.  But note that it is object dtype.  Some elements are integers, some are lists (of different sizes).

Answer (score 1):

Your lists in concatenated tuple (or list) should have same **dimension**.

You can see the line 399 in the [github source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7cd94f262b1b12d29f7903195098903cd0e9db22/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c) which implements `np.concatenate`.

```
if (PyArray_NDIM(arrays[iarrays]) != ndim) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
                            "all the input arrays must have same "
                            "number of dimensions");
            return NULL;
}
```

`PyArray_NDIM` do **gives the lengths of all of the dimensions**

In your case, the list in `failList` does not have same dimensions.
You can check it via the code below.

```
import numpy as np

failList = [[[1], [2]],
       [[3, 4, 5, 6], [7]],
       [[8], [9]],
       [[10], [11, 12]],
       [[13], [14, 15, 16]]]

goodList = [[[1], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7], [8]],
[[9], [10], [11, 12], [13], [14, 15, 16]]]


goodList2 = [[[1], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7], [8]],
       [[9], [10], [11, 12], [13], [14, 15, 16]],
       [[9], [10], [11, 12], [13], [14, 15, 16]]]

faileShapes = [np.shape(i) for i in failList]
print(faileShapes)

goodShapes = [np.shape(i) for i in goodList]
print(goodShapes)

goodShapes2 = [np.shape(i) for i in goodList2]
print(goodShapes2)

# printed console
# [(2, 1), (2,), (2, 1), (2,), (2,)]
# [(5,), (5,)]
# [(5,), (5,), (5,)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original answer (wrong):**

According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

> The arrays must have the same shape, except in the dimension corresponding to axis (the first, by default).

Your first list has the property that the inner lists are of different lengths (6 and 4, respectively). In your good lists,  all inner lists are of the same length 5.

**Edit**: Sorry, I didn't notice one of the brackets, so I mistakenly treated the shape of your `failList` as wrong.

*The correct answer is that in the failList the sublists have different shapes*:

```
>>> np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]).shape
(3,3) # because all lists have the same lengths, so NumPy treats as multi-dim array

>>> np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]).shape
(3,) # because all lists have different lengths, so NumPy treats as an array of lists
```

Comment: What do you mean? The inner lists of the first list are all of length 2

Comment: @hyst329 `goodList2 = [[[1], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7], [8]],
       [[9], [10], [11, 12], [13], [14, 15, 16]],
       [[9], [10], [11, 12], [13], [14, 15, 16,17],[0]]]` inner list lengths are `5, 5, 6` and concatenation still works

Comment: @hyst329 The lengths of the inner lists are not the same? for the good list its [1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3]

Comment: @AljoSt [1, 1, 4, 1, 1] are different (*not all* the same), as are [1, 1, 2, 1, 3]. For the fail list, [1, 1] are the same, but [4, 1] are different.

Comment: @Brenlla the paragraph above "Edit:" is wrong, i'll specially mention it.

Comment: @hyst329 So why can you concatenate my `goodList2` (comment above) but the `failList` in the question returns and error?

Comment: @Brenlla since the length your lists are [1, 1, 4, 1, 1] and [1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1] respectively. It's not the *count* of the sub-list lengths but the *differentness* of this lengths that matters. If your `goodList2[0]` were `[[1], [2], [3], [7], [8]]` instead of `[[1], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7], [8]`, the concatenation would fail.

Comment: @hyst329 Is this paragraph still correct: *Your first list has the property that the inner lists are of different lengths (6 and 4, respectively). In your good lists, all inner lists are of the same length 5.*?

Comment: @Brenlla No, it's wrong (I've marked that, but not sure if I should delete the wrong part to prevent further confusion).

Comment: @hyst329 I think you should rewritte your whole answer because it is a bit unclear.

Comment: @hyst329 So the answer is that either all the sublists need to have different length or all have to have the same length? If you make that more clear in your answer, I will accept it

Comment: Anyway, I think that this is a strange behaviour